# Backbone POST and GET to different endpoints

Tags: backbone.js

I created a Backbone model with below attributes that saves to database schema A through the `/api/books` end point. Each row is a book owned by a user.

```
url: '/api/books'
defaults: {
 'userId': 0,
 'bookId': 0,
 'bookCategory' : 'abc'
},
```

I have another database schema which contains count of books by userId which I want to fetch after each user input save. I am planning to fetch the data through another end point.

```
url: '/api/books/:userId'
defaults: {
 'userId': 0,
 'bookCount': 0,
},
```

Do I need to create two backbone models in order to save and get from two different end points?

Comment: Short and simple: yes. Unless you really don't want to do it and is okay with more complexity

Comment: I think you're confusing how the data relates to each other. Your second endpoint should be `/api/users/:userId` since a book count is a user data, not a book data. Then it makes more sense to have a `Book` model and a `User` model.